# How to rotate a Rainmeter skin

Tags: ini, rainmeter

I have a skin "Simple Clean" for rainmeter and I would like to rotate it to align it with a particular element on my wallpaper.

[image]

I want to align that visualizer with one of those lines. How can I rotate it to do so?

**Visualizer Code:**

```
[Rainmeter]
Update=0
Author=-HipHopium-
BackgroundMode=2
SolidColor=0,0,0,1

[Variables]
@include=#@#Variables.inc
AverageSize=6

;-------------------------------------------------------------
;-------------------------------------------------------------

[MeasureAudioOutput]
Measure=Plugin
Plugin=AudioLevel
Port=Output
FFTSize=4096
FFTOverlap=2048
FFTAttack=150
FFTDecay=100
FreqMin=100
FreqMax=16500
Sensitivity=32
Bands=121

;-------------------------------------------------------------
;-------------------------------------------------------------

[MeterStyle]
BarOrientation=Vertical
X=6r
Y=5
W=5
H=200
BarColor=#FontColor#

[MeterStyleR]
BarOrientation=Vertical
X=6r
Y=208
W=5
H=80
Flip=1
BarColor=#FontColor#,50

;-------------------------------------------------------------
;-------------------------------------------------------------

[Measure01]
Measure=Plugin
Plugin=AudioLevel
Parent=MeasureAudioOutput
Type=Band
BandIdx=1
AverageSize=#AverageSize#

[Measure02]
Measure=Plugin
Plugin=AudioLevel
Parent=MeasureAudioOutput
Type=Band
BandIdx=2
AverageSize=#AverageSize#
.
.
.
[Measure120]
Measure=Plugin
Plugin=AudioLevel
Parent=MeasureAudioOutput
Type=Band
BandIdx=120
AverageSize=#AverageSize#

;-------------------------------------------------------------
;-------------------------------------------------------------


[MeterBand01]
Meter=Bar
MeterStyle=MeterStyle
MeasureName=Measure01
X=65

[MeterBand02]
Meter=Bar
MeterStyle=MeterStyle
MeasureName=Measure02
.
.
.
[MeterBand120]
Meter=Bar
MeterStyle=MeterStyle
MeasureName=Measure120

;-------------------------------------------------------------
;-------------------------------------------------------------

[MeterBand01R]
Meter=Bar
MeterStyle=MeterStyleR
MeasureName=Measure01
X=65

[MeterBand02R]
Meter=Bar
MeterStyle=MeterStyleR
MeasureName=Measure02
.
.
.
[MeterBand120R]
Meter=Bar
MeterStyle=MeterStyleR
MeasureName=Measure120

;-------------------------------------------------------------
;-------------------------------------------------------------

[MeterLine]
Meter=Image
ImageName=#@#Line.png
X=0
Y=206
W=850
H=1
ImageTint=#FontColor#
```

Please note that I have used dots(...) to show that the middle code is similar to the ones above and below them just the numeric values are changed according to band index.

**Variables.inc:**

```
[Variables]

Language=English
Location=SPXX0050
Unit=m

FontColor=204,0,0
FontFace=Futura Lt

Player=Winamp                   

;-------------------------------------------------------------
;-------------------------------------------------------------

;Meny panel settings
;Enter your settings here:

Text1=- Photoshop
Text2=Google
Text3=Youtube
Text4=Gmail
Text5=Facebook
Text6=Deviantart -

Path1=C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CC 2015 (32 Bit)\Photoshop.exe
Path2=https://google.com
Path3=https://youtube.com
Path4=https://www.gmail.com
Path5=https://facebook.com
Path6=https://www.deviantart.com/browse/all/customization/skins/sysmonitor/rainmeter/?order=5

;-------------------------------------------------------------
;-------------------------------------------------------------

;Visualiser settings
;Please dont eddit these settings if you don't know what you doing

FFTSize=2048
FFTOverlap=1024
FFTAttack=650
FFTDecay=250
FreqMin=100
FreqMax=16000
Sensitivity=35
PlayerSwitch=0
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps look into TransformationMatrix, it uses a matrix to transform the shape of the skin, note that a rotation would have the skin cutoff outside the bounding rectangle, which is something you might need to fix.

```
TransformationMatrix=(Cos(Rad(#Angle#)));(-Sin(Rad(#Angle#)));(Sin(Rad(#Angle#)));(Cos(Rad(#Angle#)));#OffsetX#;#OffsetY#
```

Just put this under the meter you are trying to rotate.

Here's a link that would help understanding as well: https://docs.rainmeter.net/tips/transformation-matrix-guide/